# javascript array length gives incorrect values

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put markers in google map using postalcodes from my database.
I extracted php arry into javascript array like this:

```
 var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $postal).'"' ?>];
   var postal = new Array();
   var postcodes = new Array();
   for (var i=0;i<js_array.length;i++){
       postal[i] = "\"" + js_array[i] + "\"";
   }
   var postcodes = "[" + postal + "]";
   alert(postcodes.length);
```

There are only 2 postal codes in database. but it's showing me 19. Is there anything wrong in constructing javascript array?

And I am using this for putting marker on google map:

```
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(43.65, -79.38),5);

   for (i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
      geocoder.getLatLng(postcodes[i] + ', CANADA', function (point) {         
         if (point) {
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
         }
      });
   }
```

Is this ok to get appropriate markers on the map?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're trying to do way more stuff than you really need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to construct your array:

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($postal) ?>;
```

And I really don't know what you're trying to do with this:

```
var postcodes = "[" + postal + "]";
```

You define `postal` as an array already. Why are you trying to put square brackets around it? I think you can delete that line.

In fact, your whole loop looks unnecessary. Why stick double quotes around the values? Kill all of that. Just do:

```
var postcodes = <?php echo json_encode($postal) ?>;
alert(postcodes.length);
```

Comment: well, I am getting ["L6Y2N4","L6Y2N5"] while alerting postcodes.

Comment: @user3067928 Ok, and the problem is? That looks like a proper array to me now.

Comment: I have removed that square brackets. I am getting count:2 in alert. but, map is not placing those attribute in map.

Comment: @user3067928 See the last part of my updated answer. You can really simplify this, and you'll now have a valid javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var postcodes = "[" + postal + "]";
```

you're creating a string.  The length you're seeing is the length of that string, not the length of an array.

Comment: @user3067928 I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I think all you really need is to use JSON encoding from PHP, because that will produce ready-to-use JavaScript array initialization syntax. You shouldn't need to do anything at all other than that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are getting the length of an array, but actually a string, here.

`var postcodes = "[" + postal + "]";`

Retyping the "var" resets the variable you initially set up. Try removing that.

```
   var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $postal).'"' ?>];
   var postal = new Array();
   var postcodes = new Array();
   for (var i=0;i<js_array.length;i++){
       postal[i] = "\"" + js_array[i] + "\"";
   }
   postcodes = "[" + postal + "]";
   alert(postcodes.length);
```